# Use blob-leasing feature in the Azure cloud app

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to use blob-leasing mechanism in my Windows Azure cloud app. I am using the StorageClient api released by Azure team for my blob transactions. However, the blob-leasing is not implemented in the StorageClient api and hence I need to implement it on my own.

Has anyone done this before and has any pointers on how to do it?

Thanks.
Kapil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my recent blog post (including sample code) about how to do this: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/leasing-windows-azure-blobs-using-the-storage-client-library

Comment: has this changed? how do we acquire lesses 9 years lateR?