# windows azure blob leasing in sdk1.4

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have been using the following code which I wrote after consulting the following thread - [Use blob-leasing feature in the Azure cloud app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593050/use-blob-leasing-feature-in-the-azure-cloud-app)

```
    public static void UploadFromStreamWithLease(CloudBlob blob, Stream src, string leaseID)
    {
        string url = blob.Uri.ToString();
        if (blob.ServiceClient.Credentials.NeedsTransformUri)
        {
            url = blob.ServiceClient.Credentials.TransformUri(url);
        }

        HttpWebRequest req = BlobRequest.Put(new Uri(url), 90, blob.Properties, BlobType.BlockBlob, leaseID, 0);
        BlobRequest.AddMetadata(req, blob.Metadata);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            byte[] content = new byte[src.Length];
            writer.Write(readFully(src));
        }
        blob.ServiceClient.Credentials.SignRequest(req);
        req.GetResponse().Close();
    }
```

The readFully() method above simply gets the content from the stream to a byte[] array.

I have been using this code to upload some stuff to any blob that has a valid leaseId. This was working fine until I moved to version 1.4 of the Azure SDK. In the new version of the azure sdk, I get an error 400 in req.GetResponse() method.

Can someone please point out what has changed in azure sdk 1.4 that's screwing this up?

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

The 400 code means "bad request" there should be some additional error message, see http://paulsomers.blogspot.com/2010/10/azure-error-400-bad-request.html for some examples. You should try debugging or sniffing the network to get the error message.

There were some bugs for downloading blobs in version 1.4, but they may not affect you. However, you should upgrade to latest version.

Comment: when I use fiddler and see the response, it says that the error is due to MD5 mismatch. The error text says that the "MD5 value specified in the request did not match with the MD5 value calculated by the server."

Now this is something that started happening only after upgrading to ver1.4. The problem was also occuring at a place where I was using UploadFromStream() method. I later changed that to use the BlobStream using the CloudBlob.OpenWrite method. However, I do not know how to write to the blobstream for a blob on which I have taken a lease.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason to stay on SDK 1.4?  SDK 1.5 has been out for a few weeks now.  It also had some bugs with blobs, but they've been fixed now as well.